# how to retrieve non matching records from non-unique keys?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
Physician_key Product Month Score
  1 a       8     1 
  1 a       8     2 
  1 a       8     3 
  2 b       8     2 
  2 b       8     1
```

I am trying to retrieve only count of keys having score<=2 and I dont want to count the key even if it occurs to have a single time score>2. So in output I want something like this:
Count =2, for product b in month 8.

I am trying to do a self join with Null constraint on key for records <=2 and >2. But its still returning me first 2 rows, which I don't want.

Comment: A table is not really an RDBMS table unless it has a PK. `score` *seems* to be an unsuitable component of a compound PK

Comment: Its primary key is some sales_id, one sales_id can have multiple physician_keys

Comment: An example of your current SQL would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NOT EXISTS` clause may help:

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1 
                 FROM table tx 
                 WHERE tx.Physician_key = t.Physician_key 
                       AND tx.Product = t.Product 
                       AND Score > 2
                 );
```

This basically says "Give me all rows in the table but exclude any rows where there exists a row for this physician and product with a score > 2"

Comment: which is the table tx? and why we are selecting only 1? the physician key can have n number of values

Comment: They're both the table in your question. So we grab all records for that table where there is no entry in the same table with Score > 2.

Comment: I tried with NOT EXISTS(select physician_key from table where score>2) it returns me zero rows

Comment: @munishbansal Use the not exists in my answer. The one you have posted will prevent any rows being selected if there is *any* row in the table with score > 2.

Comment: Thanks your solution works! but about your explanation I didn't got how its stopping any row being selected if score>2

Comment: @munishbansal I've added an explanation.